# Creating a metric for counting things in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, metrics, open-telemetry

I started to add some metrics to my ASP.NET Core 6 application, but I ran into a case where I'm unsure on how exactly to implement certain kinds of metrics. The metrics are generated inside the application using the Open Telemetry Exporter, sent to Grafana Agent and then stored in Prometheus.

The kind of metric I'm having some problems with are essentially metrics that count the number of things in specific database tables. Let's say I have a table in Postgres with some hundreds of thousands or a million widgets, each widget has a type (low cardinality, maybe 10-20 types typically). What I want as a metric is current number of widgets by type.

Many examples I found use Counters, but that does not seem to be the right type here as those reset on application restart and I am interested in the absolute number of widgets, not just the rate of changes. The only appropriate metric type seems to be ObservableGauge.

The problem is that a naive ObservableGauge implementation would be too slow, I don't want to run the full DB query every time. So this needs some caching and incremental updates of that cache. So I would only run the query the first time the metric is collected, cache the result and then modify that cache whenever a widget gets added or deleted. But I don't see any nice way to keep this consistent, as while the query is running the first time some widgets might already be created or removed. I could just block any modifications to that table until that query ran, but that feels like a rather brute-force approach.

The type of metric I need seems like it should be a common case, but my potential solution here feels like reinventing the wheel. I'm wondering if I'm missing something here, or if I'm thinking about this the wrong way and maybe also the wrong metric type.

What is the right metric type for counting things in the database when you care about the specific number, not just the changes to the count?

How do you properly implement this kind of metric without running a DB query every time the metric is collected?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the right metric type for counting things in the database when you care about the specific number, not just the changes to the count?

ObservableGauge (sic!)

> How do you properly implement this kind of metric without running a DB query every time the metric is collected?

If you want to have a "correct" number without any gaps then I am not sure if there is a "proper" alternative. It depends on the architecture of your system.

You could try using Counters and apply a View that would set their Aggregation to Sum with Delta Temporality (see: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/specs/otel/metrics/data-model/#sums). However, in such scenario gaps could happen (e.g. application crashes before metrics are exported) so I would not rely on the value anyway. Also you would need something that aggregates the exported metric points...

If there is only one application instance using the database, then you could use a counter by setting the initial value at application startup (by querying the database) and updating its value at runtime. But such design would not scale as it would not allow having multiple application instances running at once.

If you would like to have a a number of items added/removed by an application instance, then it should not be that big problem and you could probably use a regular UpDownCounter. But as far as I understand, this is not what you want.

**TL;DR;** I recommend using ObservableGauge.

Answer (score 0):

From an instrument selection standpoint, you should use an ObservableCounter/ObservableUpDownCounter instead of an ObservableGauge as the measurement values (count of widgets by type) are additive. Refer to the instrument selection guidelines in the [spec](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/metrics/supplementary-guidelines.md#instrument-selection:%7E:text=If%20the%20measurement%20values%20are%20additive) for more information on this.

For the best way to achieve this, @Pellared has already made some good points in his answer.

Comment: But with a Counter the absolute value is meaningless as it is reset on restart of the application. In my case the absolute value matters.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I suggested you use ObservableCounter and not the regular Counter.